# Can an arbitrary matrix represent any linear map just by changing the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I had an $m \times n$ matrix called $M$. Now suppose I had a Linear map $T: U \rightarrow V$ with $Dim(U)=n$ and $Dim(V)=m$. Is it always possible to find bases $E$ and $F$ of $U$ and $V$ respectively such that $M$ represents the linear map $T$?

My thoughts on the question are as follows:

I feel as if this is not possible as I feel as though it would imply that all matrices are equivalent since equivalent matrices are just linear maps with respect to different bases, so if any matrix can be made to represent any linear map it would be equivalent to any other, though I not sure if this reasoning is correct.

I know that that there is a theorem which says every invertible matrix is is a change of basis matrix which implies that any invertible matrix can be made to represent the identity map just by changing the bases. This makes me think that it is possible as there dosent seem to be anything special about the identity map in particular, but maybe then it is only possible when the arbitrary matrix is invertible? but then going back to my last point this would imply all invertible matrices are equivalent so this cannot be true.

Comment: Your question will be better received if you explain what you've tried, how far you got and where you're stuck.

Comment: No, it's not possible. It depends on the rank.

Comment: ah, this makes a lot of sense since it is a sufficient condition for being equivalent if two matrices have the same rank.  So is it always possible if M and T have the same rank?

Comment: @HughKinnear Yes, in that case, it is always possible.

Comment: No, even then it's not always possible. It's not true that every matrix can be represented as the identity map in some basis. In fact the only matrix that can be so represented is the identity matrix. Here we're taking about conjugacy classes of matrices, which is complicated. For example, some matrices are diagonal in some basis (diagonalizable matrices) whereas others are not. This is solved over an algebraically closed field by Jordan canonical form, but over general fields it's more complicated.

Comment: @Matt: If I understand the OP correctly, he allows **different** bases for the domain and the codomain. In this case, the rank is a separating invariant.

Comment: I am indeed allowing for different bases in the domain and codomain